# Magento 2 error on refund - Transaction has been declined. Please try again later

Tags: magento2

I have this error on Magento 2.3.3 when I try to refund (credit memo) an order with visa (authorize.net).

```
[2020-06-17 05:43:44] main.DEBUG: array (   'request' =>    array (
    'payload_type' => 'createTransactionRequest',
    'merchantAuthentication' => 
    array (
      'name' => '8Hkxxxx',
      'transactionKey' => '2485P7zxxxxxx',
    ),
    'transactionRequest' => 
    array (
      'transactionType' => 'refundTransaction',
      'amount' => '3.12',
      'payment' => 
      array (
        'creditCard' => 
        array (
          'cardNumber' => '27xx',
          'expirationDate' => 'XXXX',
        ),
      ),
      'refTransId' => NULL,
      'order' => 
      array (
        'invoiceNumber' => '1000049324',
      ),
      'poNumber' => NULL,
      'customer' => 
      array (
        'id' => NULL,
        'email' => 'xx@gmail.com',
      ),
      'billTo' => 
      array (
        'firstName' => 'xx',
        'lastName' => 'xx',
        'company' => '',
        'address' => 'xxN Riverside Ave',
        'city' => 'St Clair',
        'state' => 'MI',
        'zip' => 'xx',
        'country' => 'US',
      ),
      'shipTo' => 
      array (
        'firstName' => 'xx',
        'lastName' => 'xx',
        'company' => '',
        'address' => 'xx N Riverside Ave',
        'city' => 'St Clair',
        'state' => 'MI',
        'zip' => 'xx079',
        'country' => 'US',
      ),
      'customerIP' => 'xx.49.12.69',
    ),   ),   'response' => '{"transactionResponse":{"responseCode":"3","authCode":"","avsResultCode":"P","cvvResultCode":"","cavvResultCode":"","transId":"0","refTransID":"","transHash":"","testRequest":"0","accountNumber":"XXXXxx52","accountType":"","errors":[{"errorCode":"6","errorText":"The credit card number is invalid."}],"transHashSha2":"581E58B78444F0AFCFAAE0F5C949EF2F773D190B63D2BBD53BA39E1F9AEF4DFB7C11F20B1E6163A5A146A8C92586BB049BE169FE40953E0A1F863EEB42BFFE55","SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator":0},"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00027","text":"The transaction was unsuccessful."}]}}', ) [] []
```

please advice
Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue , did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

`refTransId` should be provided, you have `NULL` there.
Try to dig on your side why it's passed as null to the gateway.